# Can run tomcat server without server.xml?

Tags: java, tomcat, server.xml

I am running tomcat from java class using org.apache.catalina.LifecycleEvent
Now i want to pass port number arg to start tomcat every time.
So can i remove server.xml in conf folder and run tomcat in anyway?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555838/how-to-pass-tomcat-port-number-on-command-line ?

Comment: In my question server.xml must remove from conf folder

Comment: Post your class please.

Comment: catalina.setCatalinaHome("../tomcat6/");catalina.start();

Comment: So you are talking about embedding Tomcat and running it programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running in embedded mode currently [does not](http://kishanthan.wordpress.com/2013/05/12/embedded-tomcat-tips-tricks-and-hacks/) support externalization of `server.xml`, however the given link shows how you could override some of Tomcat classes to address this.

Needless to say, there are no guarantees this will work in the next (even minor) release.

Answer (score 1):

Without server.xml you will get exception -

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/tomcat6/conf/server.xml (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
```

Instead you can pass port number runtime in server's environment variable.

Comment: Even if i pass through environment variable, /conf/server.xml file necessary? But it should not be.