# Tomcat starts with port 8080 although server.xml specifies different port number. Why?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I get this error

```
"Catalina";  Protocol handler start failed: 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind <null>:8080`.
```

This is because I have JIRA running on that port.

For Tomcat I specified port `9001` in the `server.xml` but when it is started I get Address already in use.

I cannot seem to figure out why is this.

**server.xml**

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
   <Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />

  <GlobalNamingResources>

    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />

  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">
   <Connector port="9001" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />

    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
             resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

**LOG:**

```
Nov 02, 2015 11:32:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initialize
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind <null>:8080
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:703)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:843)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:538)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:562)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)

Nov 02, 2015 11:32:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 593 ms
Nov 02, 2015 11:32:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 02, 2015 11:32:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.44
Nov 02, 2015 11:32:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
Nov 02, 2015 11:32:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
Nov 02, 2015 11:32:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
Nov 02, 2015 11:32:00 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
SEVERE: Error starting endpoint
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind <null>:8080
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:549)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.start(JIoEndpoint.java:565)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.start(Http11Protocol.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1196)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:106)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:50)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:538)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Can you post your serverl.xml?

Comment: Have you checked if 8080 is mentioned more than once in your server.xml ?

Comment: I did a windows grep for 8080 on the Tomcat folder and it was not mentioned anywhere else including in the server.xml file... This is hosting jenkins, so I also removed to jenkins directories under webapps, no luck

Comment: Have you checked the running process with which parameters it was launched ? You can configure tomcat outside server.xml, have a Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555838/how-to-pass-tomcat-port-number-on-command-line

Comment: @Geddon...post your `server.xml`

Comment: @Altmish-E-Azam updated with server.xml

Comment: How are you starting your tomcat?

Comment: @MattWatson It is installed as a Windows Service. Path to executable: "D:\Tomcat\bin\Tomcat6.exe" //RS//Tomcat6

Comment: Guys - I don't even think it is using the server.xml inside the conf directory. wtf. I just deleted the conf directory and it still started up complaining about 8080. Could it be trying to use the server.xml in JIRA, not sure how and why though.?

Comment: Do you have some sort CATALINA_HOME/CATALINA_BASE environment variable set up that's pointing to the wrong place maybe?

Comment: nope. I don't have those set as environment variables.

Comment: @MattWatson I started looking in that direction and someone installed a new Tomcat instance and a different drive that overwritten the Tomcat properties for a different catalina_home and base. This explains the port 8080..Thanks for getting me in the right direction.