# Command to change tomcat server port

Tags: linux, tomcat, ubuntu

I'm using ubuntu, and I'm in a need of some command, using which I can change the server port configurations.

Therefore, my question is...

***Is there any linux command, to update the Tomcat server connection port, as well as server shutdown port?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maksim_khokhlov answer looks promising if you want to change it at the start (it is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15556920/1584115))

Basicly you have to change the config in your server.xml.
But I dont think you can change the port at runtime without restarting.

Another way would be to write a script which first changes the server.xml and then starts tomcat.

for example with python

```
python updateserverxml.py 8888
(and in this file you replace the port and start the server.)
```

Or another way could be using docker and map the exposed port from your standardport to your desired port.

**maksim_khokhlov answer below**:

Change your server.xml so that it will use port numbers expanded from properties instead of hardcoded ones:

```
<Server port="${port.shutdown}" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
...
  <Connector port="${port.http}" protocol="HTTP/1.1"/>
...
</Server>
```

Here's how you can start in Linux (assuming your current directory is CATALINA_HOME):

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Dport.shutdown=8005 -Dport.http=8080" bin/startup.sh
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer!
.. I'm trying these steps.. but getting 

-bash: bin/startup.sh: Permission denied
... I'm trying maksim_khokhlov answer

Comment: maybe if you want to start the server on port 1024 or below you need admin rights (root). Anyway does it work with sudo / root ?

Comment: my bad...
i didnt had the permission that time.. it works properly

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to conf folder in tomcat installation directory

2) Edit connection properties in server.xml file

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```