# How to map an outgoing host/port from a container to a different port

Tags: tomcat, docker, mariadb

I have a smallish webapp that connects to a mariadb database.  I have Tomcat running in one container and mariadb in another container.  Tomcat refers to the mariadb instance with a JDBC url specified in the Context.xml file, specifying the current fqhn and port 3306.

I now have to duplicate this configuration, such that I have two instances of the webapp on the box, comprising four containers, two running Tomcat, and two running Mariadb.  It's easy enough to do the simple port mapping on "docker run", so that each of the Tomcat instances are reachable through different ports, and similarly for the mariadb instances.

What's not clear to me is how to map the OUTGOING host:port reference from the Tomcat container to the mariadb instance.  The Context.xml file in the image specifies the JDBC url for the database, using the current fully-qualified host name and the default port of 3306.

I have the ability to change the single image so it can work with both instances, but I still have to have a single image with a single JDBC url.  With the first container pair, it has to reach the original mariadb instance running on 3306.  The second container pair, even though it's specifying port 3306, has to connect to port 3307.

Is this somehow done with the "--link" command-line option?

**Update**:

This would be easier if an existing application wasn't running, and I could just hack through this until it's working.  I have to make sure I step through this carefully, to minimize disruption.  I have to make one change to the image source code, being the JDBC url in the context.xml file.  I changed that to "`jdbc:mysql://db:3306/estimatordb`".

Although I build the application WAR file with Gradle on my desktop (or on the Jenkins instance), the Docker image is only built on the Jenkins instance.  I had been running the containers on the target host in a systemd file, just doing "docker run ...".  In the Jenkins build, through ssh I do a "docker pull" of the image name and then a "docker stop" to stop the existing container so it will restart with the new image.

In the interim, I'm going to change the image name that I build (just adding "2" to the name), and I'm commenting out the "ssh docker stop" for now.  I'm not sure what that will translate to with compose.  Obviously "docker-compose stop" is a starting point, but that gets confusing if I'm making changes to the compose file in this build.

My "docker-compose.yml" file is a source file in my project, so I guess I will do a "ssh docker-compose -f -", piping in my compose file.

The following is what I've thrown together for the "docker-compose.yml" file, but I haven't verified this at all:

```
version: '2'
services:
  estimator:
    image: tomcat-estimator2
    ports:
      - "8889:8080"
      - "445:443"
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db:db
  db:
    image:  mariadb:10.1.22
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime
      - /opt/app/estimator/databases/estimator/mysql:/var/lib/mysql  
  estimator-automation:
    image: tomcat-estimator2
    ports:
      - "8890:8080"
      - "446:443"
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime
    depends_on:
      - db-automation
    links:
      - db-automation:db
  db-automation:
    image:  mariadb:10.1.22
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime
      - /opt/app/estimator/databases/estimator-automation/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

Notice that the port numbers are 1+ the ports for the existing application, as I don't want to bring that down until I'm sure this will work.

Any comments about this will be useful.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why one webapp connects to the database on port 3306 and the other on port 3307? If I follow your question correctly, there is a 1-2-1 mapping between application and database?

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. It's one webapp, and two instances of the webapp. The Context.xml file in the image specifies port 3306. I can run the two instances of tomcat and the two instances of mariadb so that their listen ports don't conflict, but both instances of the webapp are trying to connect to the database on port 3306 unconditionally. I somehow need to make one of those tomcat containers transparently map that access to port 3306 to be port 3307.

Comment: Bear with me David, it's been a long day, but to confirm: container A -> Database A on port 3306 and container B -> Database B on port 3306? Is the port conflict here because you're connecting the application to the database via a port bound on the host e.g. `docker run -p 3307:3306`?

Comment: The Context.xml file in the image has a JDBC url of "jdbc:mysql://<fqhn>:3306/estimatordb".  This works fine with a single instance of the application, comprising the two containers. I need to use the same images to run two additional containers, one for tomcat and one for mariadb.  The mariadb container is easy, as I only have to map the input port. I can map the input port for the tomcat container (for instance, 8081:8080), but I don't know how to map the OUTPUT port.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr, are you running these in two different compose? And is the host port mapping needed? If it can work without changing anything and non static port mapping on host. does that work for you?

Comment: I have a working solution now, but I'll answer some questions about it. In a single compose file, I'm manifesting two separate instances of the same application, each with a different "application name" (that describes the semantic scope of the application), and a different database. The two webapp containers are driven by the same image, which has a single JDBC url. I use the "links" mechanism in compose to make that single JDBC url connect to different database containers in each of the two instances of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking those use cases like specifying resources that are needed to run an application are usually handled (especially in the docker context) by providing a way to pass such information as command line parameters or via environment. For more information on this, have a look at [the great manifesto of the 12 factor app](https://12factor.net), especially [the section on configuration](https://12factor.net/config).

For your concrete problem, I'm sure there are ways to inject this information into the tomcat config, for example as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34018527/passing-tomcat-parameters-to-docker). So you could already solve your problem by running two database containers on different ports and pass the corresponding connections strings to your two tomcat containers.

But this is not the full solution yet. When you think about the combination of a tomcat container with a database as one deployment, you can make use of the docker virtual networks and connect such a setup without even publishing a port of the database to the outside world. When two containers are in the same network, you can reference them using their given names, so that your databases are always reachable as `mydatabase:3306` within the docker virtual network. This works especially easy when using a system like docker-compose that handles such namespacing for you and lets you define your whole stack as one compose file. Please have a look at [the getting started for `docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/) that does exactly this with a python application accessing a redis instance.

Comment: Sigh.  I had a feeling I was stepping into the realm of compose. I guess I can't delay that any longer.

Comment: This is not really a feature that is only available when using docker-compose because everything that compose does can also be handled by some specific docker commands (e.g. with --network and --network-alias). But in my opinion, using compose for such tasks has a much better experience than running containers manually in the correct order. So I'd suggest to have a look at docker-compose. It's worth the effort!

Comment: Except for some small changes, the compose file up above worked perfectly on the first try.  I still have some admin and automation work left to do, but it was an effective solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind mount a unique `context.xml` to each container with the `-v` option.

For example on the host:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/container
$ cd /tmp/container
$ vi container1_context.xml # Edit JDBC url
$ vi container2_context.xml # Edit JDBC url
$ docker run ... -v /tmp/container/container1_context.xml:<path/to/context.xml> tomcat
$ docker run ... -v /tmp/container/container2_context.xml:<path/to/context.xml> tomcat
```