# Set port number when starting apache tomcat- Window Services through command line

Tags: c#, tomcat, cmd, tomcat7

I want to start tomcat service through cmd line on my windows machine. I have Tomcat7.exe in tomcat bin folder. I know that, to start command I am suppose to run:

```
c:\..\bin>tomcat7.exe start
```

Can I set port number before start, like in

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Dport.shutdown=8005 -Dport.http=8080" bin\startup.bat
```

Ref: [How to pass tomcat port number on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555838/how-to-pass-tomcat-port-number-on-command-line)
But I dont have batch file.

How can I set port before i start service? Can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to set the port

```
c:\..\bin>Tomcat7.exe //US//tomcat7 --"JvmOptions=-Dport.shutdown=8005;-Dport.http=8081"
C:\..\bin>tomcat7.exe start
```

this will start the service with port number 8081.