# Tomcat, catalina.sh run on port from command line

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee

Is it possible to change the **port** for catalina.sh run command?

By default it runs on 8080.

I know i can change it in the **servers.xml** , but on upgrade one has to continuously fiddle with that.

Comment: Possibly, question duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555838/how-to-pass-tomcat-port-number-on-command-line

Comment: is your steps like below link below link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415578/how-to-change-tomcat-port-number

Comment: @elham_jahani i want to do it through the command line, changing through the server.xml is awkward and not as easy. I think gregories way might the best option though, although I have to repeat the step when i download a new tomcat version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you use the link below :

[How to change tomcat port number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415578/how-to-change-tomcat-port-number)

and if you want to change it with command line, you can use this command :

```
sed -i -e 's/8080/8081/' /TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml
```